# Present two different dimensions in MDX as hierarchy

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, dimensions, iccube

I have two different dimensions i want to present in MDX Query with drilldown

**Dim 1:**

```
Country, CountryId

Italy,1

Mexico,2

England,3
```

**dim 2:**

```
Product, ProductId

Shoes,1

Shirts,2

Bags,3
```

**Fact_Data:**

```
Country,Product,Amount

1,2,33

3,1,50

2,3,64

1,1,100

3,1,70

2,2,44
```

when i join the dimensions in MDX Query:

select [Measures].[SaleAmount] on 0,
crossjoin([Country].[Country].[Country].[Italy],[Product].[Product].[Product].[Product]) on 1
from [cube]

the data presented will be:

```
italy   Shoes  100

        Shirts 33

        Bags   0

Mexico  Shoes  0

        Shirts 44

        Bags   64
...
```

And i want to present the data with drilldown option from country to product

```
+italy   133
+Mexico  108
+England 120
```

I'm using icCube

Comment: Sorry, can't understand. Could you create an example with in-memory data and add it as example ?

Comment: I've Edit the Question

Answer (score 1):

The complicated part is solving this in the schema, two options there

- Create a new dimension that is a crossjoin dim1*dim2, that defines a multiple value key for the last level + remove name unique on the last level. You could remove Dim1 and Dim2 and define them as hierarchies in Dim1Dim2 newly created dimension.
- Use categories, for now it's a bit brute you've to create one by one member (contact us directly if you want to go this way).

The easy and **recommended** way, use the Navigation settings to define the drilldown strategy in the reporting at chart level.

[image]

Comment: Hey, i've tried to do the drill down approach on my production schema (not the example above). and i get the drill down new rows like a union under the selected country. in your example. we will see Indonesia,Personal,Server,Gold... like a union on rows and not as a hierarchy as presented. what can be the reason for that? is it relates to the dimension definitions?

Comment: check the mdx generated on the server side (monitoring). btw, i forgot to add Filter By in my example so you've [Personal] for [Indonesia] and not all...

Comment: can you add an example how to do the filter. cause i've checked the monitoring and my problem was that i didn't got the lowest members only. when i took the lowest member from my hierarchy it worked as expected.  But now i need to filter by the selected column in the table. how to do it? because i've tried to put an event name 'On Column Selection' and put @{eventName:asMdx} or @{eventName:asFilterInitialSelection} under 'Filter Info Renderer' and it doesn't work. can you make an example or edit your answer?

Comment: it's a bug, we're still in RC mode, thanks for finding out (no workaround for this one)